# How to make a global function for push/pop decision for all viewcontrollers (vc, vc2, vc3, vc4..)

Tags: ios, swift, popup, push, rootviewcontroller

Can I make a global function for push/pop decision for all viewcontrollers (vc, vc2 ,vc3, vc4, ...)?

```
func poprootviewcontroller(view: UIView?,title: String?,f: CGRect?)->UIButton {
    return btn
```

like so?

Comment: which programming language you use? which framework?...give us more details..

Comment: language->swift,

Comment: btn.frame = f ?? CGRect.init(x: screen_width*0.30, y: screen_width*0.30, width: screen_width*0.15, height: screen_width*0.15),                                           and have different measurements for diff. btn for all views if they will have same then overlap each other